# difficulty returning moderately complex F# type signature

Tags: f#

I've defined F# Tree and Stack types, with a pop member on the Stack. I can't get the type signature right on results of the pop. Here is my code up until I try to use pop:

```
type Tree<'a> =
    | Tree of 'a * 'a Tree * Tree<'a>
    | Node of 'a 
    | None

type 'a Stack =
    | EmptyStack 
    | Stack of 'a * 'a Stack 
    member x.pop = function
        | EmptyStack -> failwith "Empty stack"
        | Stack(hd, tl) -> (hd:'a), (tl:Stack<_>)

let myTree = Tree("A", Tree("B", Node("D"), None), Tree("C", Tree("E", None, Node("G")),  Tree("F", Node("H"), Node("J"))))

let myStack = Stack((myTree, 1), Stack.EmptyStack)
```

Now I've tried various ways to return the pop, and each one throws a different kind of error with the signature:

```
let (tree, level), z = myStack.pop
```

throws:
stdin(22,24): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    ('a * 'b) * 'c
but here has type
    (Tree * int) Stack -> (Tree * int) * (Tree * int) Stack

```
//let (tree:Tree<_>, level:int), z:Stack<Tree<_>*int> = myStack.pop
let (tree:Tree<_>, level:int), z:Stack<'a> = myStack.pop
//let (tree:Tree<'a>, level:int), _ = myStack.pop
//let (tree:Tree<string>, level:int), z:Stack<Tree<string>*int> = myStack.pop
```

The attempt uncommented above throws:
stdin(16,46): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    (Tree<'b> * int) * 'c
but here has type
    'a Stack

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `pop` here is an instance method taking one argument (due to `function`), but you want it to be an instance method taking zero arguments (i.e. unit), like

```
type 'a Stack =
    | EmptyStack 
    | Stack of 'a * 'a Stack 
    member x.pop() =
        match x with
        | EmptyStack -> failwith "Empty stack"
        | Stack(hd, tl) -> (hd:'a), (tl:Stack<_>)
```

and then call it like

```
let (tree,level), z = myStack.pop()
```

**[Edit]**

But actually, since `Stack` is immutable here, it doesn't really make sense to implement `pop` as an instance member, since then it's really more like peek. So you might want to implement it as a function in a companion module (or / and as a static member of `Stack` for compatibility with other .NET languages):

```
type 'a Stack = \\'
    | EmptyStack 
    | Stack of 'a * 'a Stack 

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Stack =
    let pop = function
        | EmptyStack -> failwith "Empty stack"
        | Stack(hd, tl) -> (hd:'a), (tl:Stack<_>)
```

and call it like

```
let (tree, level), z = Stack.pop myStack
```